# unable to Curl or SoapClient Any remote_server:8080 port on Directadmin Centos

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, wsdl

I am Trying To Connect a Soap Api by php

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

    $opts = array(
        'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
    );
    $params = array ('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'verifypeer' => false, 'verifyhost' => false, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 5, 'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) );
    $url = "http://x.x.x.x:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl";
    $client =new SoapClient($url,$params);
    $result = $client->sendMessageOneToMany(array(
        "username"  => 'xxxxx',
        "password"  => 'xxxxx',
        "originator"  => "50004132311446",
        "destination"  => $numbers,
        "content"  => $massage,

    ));
```

but it allways got an

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'x.x.x.x:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl";' : failed to load external entity "x.x.x.x:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl";")

error !

I also Tried to Curl This WSDL but I got

```
[root@myhost ~]# curl http://x.x.x.x:8080/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl
```

curl: (7) Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 8080: Connection timed out

Error !

so i also tried to curl portquiz.net:8080/ for test and i got timeout again !

is there some rule in firewall that block me to send request to 8080 ports !

how can i unblock it in centos directadmin vps ?

Answer (score 0):

often this happens because that your ip address has been blocked , or there are an issues with the server it self .

for more info about that , [libcurl error codes](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

> CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)
>
> Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

for your command :

```
curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl
```

when executing it in my own pc i got the response normally .

so you will need to use proxy in your [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class

> For making an HTTP connection through a proxy server, the options
>   proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_login and proxy_password are also
>   available.

so you will need to add some params to your `$params` array ass follows :

```
$params['proxy_host'] = "proxy_ip";
$params['proxy_port'] = "proxy_port";
```

it's also possible (personally i recommend [this](https://github.com/w3zone/crawler)) to use procedures [libcurl](http://php.net/curl) functions or packages built on it.

if you want to use the cli way , so your command may be some thing like this :

```
curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl -x "ip_address:ip_port"
```

for socks5 ips

```
curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/ws-relay/MessageRelayService?wsdl -x "ip_address:ip_port" --socks5
```

Comment: it was an issues in my firewall setting , support center solved it for me ! but how can i unblock such things in centos , i saw everything in google for it !

Comment: are you trying to crawl your own server ? or a foreign server ?

Comment: It is An Sms Api Sevrer (foreign serve)

Comment: then you will have to either 1- contact them to unblock you , 2- register to their api , 3- using proxy server to connect to their api .

Comment: my own server firewall was the problem , not them